# Hyperellipsoid confidence region

Tags: r, ellipse, confidence-interval

The R function `ellipse()` (package: ellipse) allows to generate the coordinates of confidence regions for two parameters. Does anyone know how to generate the coordinates of hyperellipsoid confidence regions for D>2 parameters?

Comment: If you do not get an answer here try asking on the statistics forum: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions  You might need to use the delta method and write the code yourself, but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, I think what you want is described in the "Introduction to rggobi" document which you can find with a search.  They call it a graphical manova.  I implemented it in 3D in the function `makeEllipse`in the package `ChemoSpec`.  If you study that and related functions, I think you can extend it to more dimensions.  You can see it in action by running the examples in `plotScores3D` or `plotScoresRGL`.  Good luck.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but your code works straightforward with D>=2... ;) This was more or less what I needed. Thanks!

library(ChemoSpec)
w <- rnorm(10, 0, 1)
x <- rnorm(10, 2, 0.5)
y <- rnorm(10, -2, 2)
z <- rnorm(10, -10, 4)
ell <- makeEllipsoid(cbind(w,x,y,z), cl = 0.99)
plot(data.frame(ell), col = "red", pch = 20, cex = 0.3)

Comment: Well, that's even better then!  Glad to be of help, but I was really just following the code by the ggobi folks mentioned at ggobi.org  I could never have come up with the approach by myself!